# Which paid accounts, subscriptions should we get before creating a Google Action for an organization?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am new to Google Actions Development. My organization wants to create some Google Actions for our project so that those Actions can directly call our APIs through Google Assistance and get the required data. Earlier I created POC using my personal Gmail account but as now we want to use it for organizational/commercial purpose I want to know which paid Google developer accounts, subscriptions do I need to purchase to use it for my organization.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only paid account you'll need is the Firebase. When you create an Action from the DialogFlow platform it automatically creates a Firebase project for you. In order to make external calls, you'll have to update it to a paid account. So if your organization creates a Google account (or use an existing one of course) to create an action, they can just update the Firebase project to the paid and add you as a developer. If you're interested in a more secure agent, I'd suggest you to have a look at the Dialogflow Enterprise version. It has the same capabilities, but offers the security of the GCP.

Comment: Thanks Eliza, I have some more doubt. 
1. When we deploy our node.js code with firebase functions through dialogflow where exactly it gets deployed, on Google Cloud?
2. Is there any other website to handle my deployments?

Comment: Unless you use the online editor for the fulfillment (which I wouldn't recommend), you can deploy your function anywhere you want and provide that endpoint to DialogFlow. In fact, you don't even have to stick to nodejs if you don't want to. If you search for dialogflow fulfillment on GitHub you'll find snippets and the starter code for more languages.